# data not copying from one sheet to another correctly

Tags: vba, excel

Arrgg... anyone able to help me with the below VBA?

It's to cycle through 5 or so sheets and if there's any names on a list in sheet DevList it copies them to the OHD Leave Tracker sheet. For some reason the third column isn't copying for some of the records it finds. It seems to be the Array i'm using for the sheets, as if I only put one sheet name there it works fine.

Alternatively, if you can help me find a better way, as this was patched together rather quickly on Friday afternoon.

```
Sub CopyYes()
 Dim c As Range
 Dim thisrow As Variant
 Dim j As Integer
 Dim Source As Worksheet
 Dim Target As Worksheet
 Dim arr As Variant

 arr = Array("Ind", "FAP", "YEE", "ABY", "LSL", "OHD's")
 j = 6 ' Start copying to row 6 in target sheet
 For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

 ' Change worksheet designations as needed
 'Set Source = Worksheets(arr(i))
 Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OHD Leave Tracker")


 For Each c In Worksheets(arr(i)).Range("F1:F1000") ' Do 1000 rows
 If c = "Approved" Then
 thisrow = c.Row
 Target.Cells(j, 2) = Worksheets(arr(i)).Cells(thisrow, 1)
 Target.Cells(j, 3) = Worksheets(arr(i)).Cells(thisrow, 2)
 Target.Cells(j, 4) = Worksheets(arr(i)).Cells(thisrow, 3)
 j = j + 1
 End If
 Next c
 Next i
 Dim Lastrow As Long

 Lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 Worksheets("OHD Leave Tracker").Range("A6:A" & Lastrow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B6,DevList!A:A,1,FALSE)),""Delete"",""Keep"")"

 Last = Worksheets("OHD Leave Tracker").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 For i = Last To 1 Step -1
 If Worksheets("OHD Leave Tracker").Cells(i, "A").Value = "Delete" Then
 Worksheets("OHD Leave Tracker").Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
 End If
 Next i

 End Sub
```

Comment: Hard to tell what you're referring to. I assume the copy data is failing in the first loop, but there's no DevList referred to any any of your array elements. Which part of the code is failing?

Comment: Maybe try changing this first. I cleaned up the code but I wont post that at the moment.
 Lastrow = Target.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Added reference to the OHD Leave sheet

Comment: Sorry dbmitch, I forgot to mention that I added a helper column in the OHD Leave Tracker sheet in column A, which then does a VLookup in the DevList sheet
No luck with that, Captain Grumpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your data.  There is no reason that your code should not work the same in all cases.

### Here is a better way:

- Use an array to collect the data and then write all the data in one operation
- Use a collection to filter out values that exist in the DevList
- I added a line that will stop the code execution in the value in column 3 is empty

  - Debug.Assert Trim(.Cells(1, 3)) <> ""

---

```
Sub CopyYes()
    Dim Start: Start = Timer
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet
    Dim arrData As Variant: ReDim arrData(2, 0)
    Dim DevList As Object: Set DevList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    With Worksheets("DevList")
        For Each c In .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            DevList.Add c.Text
        Next c
    End With

    For Each Source In Worksheets(Array("Ind", "FAP", "YEE", "ABY", "LSL", "OHD's"))
        Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OHD Leave Tracker")
        With Source
            For Each c In .Range("F1", .Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
                If c = "Approved" Then
                    With c.EntireRow
                        If Not DevList.Contains(.Cells(1, 2).Text) Then
                            ReDim Preserve arrData(2, j)
                            arrData(0, j) = .Cells(1, 1)
                            arrData(1, j) = .Cells(1, 2)
                            arrData(2, j) = .Cells(1, 3)
                            Debug.Assert Trim(.Cells(1, 3)) <> ""
                            j = j + 1
                        End If
                    End With
                End If
            Next c
        End With
    Next Source

    Target.Range("B6:D" & Rows.Count).Clear
    Target.Range("B6:D6").Resize(j) = Application.Transpose(arrData)
    Debug.Print Timer - Start
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Shai Rado.   I forgot that I had that reference.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that's mostly working, however the line 
    `Debug.Assert Trim(.Cells(1, 3)) <> ""`
is stopping the macro from running, if I comment this out though it runs fine (and fast).